# Sql Server string Prefix doubt

Tags: sql

I'm learning T-SQL. 
Why the strings are prefixed with N in every example I've seen?

What are the pros or cons of using this prefix?

Please make it clear that if my column has datatype as nvarchar /vachar then is it mandatory to provide values using 'N' as prefix or it just a system that we are following.

Answer (score 4):

N'foo' stores the string "foo" using Unicode.

'foo' stores it using ASCII.

This doesn't matter if you're just using a-zA-Z0-9, but will become necessary if you need to store other characters such as "រៀន".

See also [Write differences between varchar and nvarchar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36081/51819) for more information.

If you are inserting the data into a field defined one way or the other, the system will *usually* convert the data automatically.  Assigning 'foo' to an nvarchar field can be expected to work, but assigning N'រៀន' to a varchar won't.